# Django Inner Join Queryset

Tags: python, django, inner-join, django-queryset

I'm working with Django and I need to do a queryset using two inner joins.

I have three models A, B, and C and I want to do a query like the following in psql:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a FROM A
INNER JOIN B ON B.a_id = A.id
INNER JOIN C ON C.b_id = B.id;
```

Models: (only included relevant fields)

```
class A(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)

class B(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    a = models.ForeignKey(A, null=True, blank=True,on_delete=models.SET_NULL)

class C(models.Model):
    b = models.ForeignKey(B, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

So everything in C links back to one thing in B and everything in B links back to one thing in A. I want to try and get all the distinct elements in A that have something in C.

How do I do this using django queryset? Thanks.

Comment: It would be great if you show your models, and tell what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: @karthikr added the models and what i'm trying to do

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`A.objects.filter(b__c__isnull=False)` results a sql w/ same result:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.* FROM a 
INNER JOIN b ON (a.id = b.a_id)
INNER JOIN c ON (b.id=c.b_id)
WHERE c.id IS NOT NULL;
```

P.S. Why do you use `IntegerField` instead of `AutoField` for ids?

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I actually use AutoField, I just copied it over wrong.